# Django admin: Filter many2many relations independently

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Currently, with the Django admin view, I can filter on groups like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/user/?groups__exact=1
```

to get all users in group 1, or

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/user/?groups__in=1,2,3
```

to get all users in group 1,2 or 3.

How can I filter users

- who are not in group 1, or
- who are in group 2 and 3, but not 4.

Ideally, I’d like to trigger them using independent URL parameters, e.g. something like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/accounts/user/?groups__1=1&groups__2=1&groups__3=0
```

Comment: Can you provide some code on how you filtered groups currently? It sounds like you might need to use a conditional to filter out groups.

Comment: Currently, I’m using nothing special, just `list_filter = ('groups', ...` in the Admin view for Users.

Comment: Try using a conditional wrapped around that statement. Also, you will need to check if you can distinguish between group items, which I'm sure you can, but more info will be available in the docs. I don't want to post this as the answer, cause I will definitely get downvoted for it, so I recommend you test out a conditional-based solution and post an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement custom admin filter, here is simple example:
http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2011/11/custom-admin-filter-specification.html

Comment: Thanks, its a good start. But will it be possible to make the choices dynamic? I’d like one checkbox for each group, without hard-coding the groups.